# Show grid lines over image in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, numpy, pyqtgraph

I'm drawing an image in pyqtgraph, and I'd like to be able to see the grid lines. But the grid lines are always drawn underneath the image, so any black areas of the image obscure the grid. Here's a fairly minimal example:

```
import matplotlib  # necessary for interactive plots in pyqtgraph
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
n = 100000
sigma_y = 1e-3
sigma_x = 1e-3
x0 = np.matrix([np.random.normal(0, sigma_x, n), np.random.normal(0, sigma_y, n)])
bins = 30
histogram, x_edges, y_edges = np.histogram2d(np.asarray(x0)[0], np.asarray(x0)[1], bins)
x_range = x_edges[-1] - x_edges[0]
y_range = y_edges[-1] - y_edges[0]

imv = pg.ImageView(view=pg.PlotItem())
imv.show()
imv.setPredefinedGradient('thermal')
imv.getView().showGrid(True, True)
imv.setImage(histogram, pos=(x_edges[0], y_edges[0]), scale=(x_range / bins, y_range / bins))
```

Here's what I see (after zooming out a little). You can see that the black area of the image obscures the grid lines.

[image: pyqtgraph image screenshot]

**EDIT**: it's possible in the GUI to change the black colour to transparent (not my first choice, but an OK workaround for now), so you can see the grid below the image. That works OK but I can't figure out how to do it in code. How do I get the lookup table out of the `ImageView` to modify it?

Comment: The color scale consists of a gradient between a few colors. These are indicated by the triangles to the right of the color bar. If you click on the black triangle on the bottom, a dialog will pop up from which you can change the color at that set point. Set the alpha component to 0 to make the lower and of the scale transparent. See it this works for you. I'm sure it can be done programmatically as well.

Comment: That's actually not bad, and better looking than I expected. But I'd still like to see a (faint) grid line actually above the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did.

```
glw = pyqtgraph.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
pw = glw.addPlot(0, 0)

# Fix Axes ticks and grid
for key in pw.axes:
    ax = pw.getAxis(key)

    # Set the grid opacity
    if grid_is_visible:
        ax.setGrid(grid_opacity * 255)
    else:
        ax.setGrid(False)

    # Fix Z value making the grid on top of the image
    ax.setZValue(1)
```

This did cause some other issue, I think. It may have been the context menu or it had to do with panning and zooming, because of how Qt was signaling the events. One axes got the event priority and prevented the event from propagating for the other axes to pan and zoom. I submitted a pull request to pyqtgraph, so that might not be an issue anymore. I can't remember what caused the problem though. It may work just fine for you. I was doing a lot of other things like changing the background color and changing the viewbox background color which caused some small issues.

As a note I also changed the image z value. You shouldn't have to though.

```
imv.setZValue(1)
```

Comment: Yes! That works. You're right about the issue though (I'm using pyqtgraph 0.10.0). With the image below the grid, I can only pan vertically. That's possibly annoying enough that I'll leave the grid where it is.

Comment: I made a fix in pyqtgraph and submitted a pull request for it. You can go in your site packages python folder and edit pyqtgraph. https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/565  Or you could use my version of pyqtgraph if you really need it, but I don't always update my version and you would miss new stuff. `pip install git+http://github.com/HashSplat/pyqtgraph@mydevelop` You have to have git installed.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I found your PR. It's just a cosmetic thing so I'll leave it for now, but I'll keep an eye on your PR; if it gets accepted I'll use the develop branch.

Comment: Please to add in usefulness about `grid_opacity` and `grid_is_visible`?  Where from? How to use?